# Data loss in rosserial for arduino to pc

Tags: ros, arduino, ros-kinetic, rosserial, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there.

I using rosserial to communicate pc to arduino.
I use timer interruptions for publishing.

But, when I use timer interruptions, rosserial said "wrong checksum for topic id and msg".
This error occurs in almost same timing, such as one in 20 seconds.

Is there anyone who understands the cause?

Thanks in advance.

My codes here.

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/UInt64.h>
#include <CurieTimerOne.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;

std_msgs::UInt64 msgs;
ros::Publisher unnamed_publisher("empty_topic", &msgs);

void intFunc()
{
    msgs.data = millis();
    unnamed_publisher.publish(&msgs);
}

void setup()
{
    nh.initNode();
    nh.advertise(unnamed_publisher);

    // Interrupt 50 hz
    int secToMicro = 1e6;
    int Hz = 100;
    CurieTimerOne.start(secToMicro / Hz, intFunc);
}

void loop()
{
    delay(100);
    nh.spinOnce();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281640/data-loss-in-rosserial-for-arduino-to-pc/) by [urad](https://answers.ros.org/users/33533/urad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have never encounter this issue, but you should not publish within an interrupt handler.

It is generally a bad idea to do complex things (such as serialize and send through a serial port) during an interrupt (note that your `millis()` counter will stop counting while you are in the handler so you should make it as short as possible).

You should set a flag in the interrupt and publish in your main loop if the flag is set.

Something like:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/UInt64.h>
#include <CurieTimerOne.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;

std_msgs::UInt64 msgs;
ros::Publisher unnamed_publisher("empty_topic", &msgs);
bool publish_flag = false;

void intFunc()
{
    msgs.data = millis();
    publish_flag = true;
}

void setup()
{
    nh.initNode();
    nh.advertise(unnamed_publisher);

    // Interrupt 50 hz
    int secToMicro = 1e6;
    int Hz = 100;
    CurieTimerOne.start(secToMicro / Hz, intFunc);
}

void loop()
{
    if(publish_flag)
    {
        unnamed_publisher.publish(&msgs);
        publish_flag = false;
    }

    nh.spinOnce();
    delay(1); // optional
}
```

---

Originally posted by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) with karma: 544 on 2018-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [urad](https://answers.ros.org/users/33533/urad/) on 2018-02-07**:
Thank you for your answer.
I didn't know how to gently use microcontrollers, especially about interrupts.
I follow your advice and now it seems correctly works very well.

I am grateful for your support.
Thanks!

**Comment by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on 2018-02-08**:
Your welcome.
If your question is answered, please mark the answer as correct so others will find this problem as solved.